# How do you get Symbols from the Windows linker?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker, osdev

I am wondering if there is a way to output symbols from the windows linker. I know it will dump a symbol map but I want something that I can load in a debugger.

If the linker doesn't output symbols can I get them from an existing obj file?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I missed this in the docs but you justs need to supply `/PDB:file.pdb /DEBUG:FULL` as the linker arguments. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx19e36.aspx

Comment: You don't need the `PDB` switch unless you want to change the file name. By default, throwing the `DEBUG` switch will emit a PDB file with the same name as the generated binary and the PDB extension, which is almost always what you want.